# Windows 10 - performance issue: randomly occurring latency at basic tasks (opening a window, reacting to keys type or mouse click)

Tags: windows-10, performance, latency

**The PC:**

- HP Envy 15 Latop
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4702MQ CPU @ 2.20GHz (bought around year 2015)
- upgraded ~2 years ago to SSD HDD & 16 GB RAM

  - current Windows 10 installed at that moment, automatic updates ON.

In the last ~1 week, the OS started moving with latency.
It usually works normal, **except** when it shows latency at very basic tasks like

- reacting to a mouse click (I middle-click a link, it can take ~2 seconds until that link is opened in a new browser tab)
- keyboard input (even while I wrote this post, it happened several times that the cursor simply freezes for ~2 seconds, I don't see anything new appearing in the edit box as I type, and then everything "catches-up" and appears).

Asides from this, no other striking issues.
Haven't run **heavy** performance tests, but could watch 1080p movies without the CPU overheating or the CPU coolers "taking off".

**Nothing was changed/added** at the laptop recently.

- no new hardware (not even new device connected on USB)
- no new software
- no programs added to start-up with windows.

Also, **even while the issue occurres**:

- CPU temperature is normal
- Memory & CPU workload is normal.

I'll probably end up reinstalling the windows, but I'm asking more of a curiosity:
**Has anybody had similar issues ? Any ideas what could be causing this ?**

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked your hard disks for SMART errors?

Comment: Yes. Ran a full system diagnostics. No error / warning found...

Comment: It is unusual for a mouse/keyboard to stutter like that unless it is a hardware issue. You don’t really mention any details about the system. Is it a laptop, desktop, custom build, make/model, etc… could be as simple as a problem with the keyboard/mouse combo.

Comment: It's the OS that stutters, not the mouse/keyboard.
I type, what I type is "stored" in memory and all comes back after the ~2 seconds of freezing. Or I hit Alt-Tab and everything is frozen for ~2 seconds, then the action happens. Or I close 2 browser tabs, everything stas frozen for ~2 seconds and then the 2 browser tabs are closed.
I also edited the post, the system is an HP Laptop.